# Edited title: Woocommerce create order status that doesn't mark order as uneditable

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a new custom order status in my woocommerce install "Awaiting shipping Calculation", my client has some products which are very complex and the shipping must be worked out manually then an invoice sent.

I followed a guide  Which has created the Custom order status, but whenever the order has that status, the order is no longer editable

I want my new custom status to still leave the order editable.

---

Edit have changed some of the details above so the whole question makes more sense:

Turns out I was taking completely the wrong approach, there is a function is_editable() in the file abstract-wc-order.php

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L2469

```
/**
 * Checks if an order can be edited, specifically for use on the Edit Order screen
 *
 * @access public
 * @return bool
 */
public function is_editable() {
    if ( ! isset( $this->editable ) ) {
        $this->editable = in_array( $this->get_status(), array( 'pending', 'on-hold', 'auto-draft' ) );
    }
    return apply_filters( 'wc_order_is_editable', $this->editable, $this );
}
```

if I add my new order status into that array then the whole thing works the way I want it to, however, as soon as I update woocommerce, that change will be overwritten.

is there something I can put in my plugin code which will add my new status to that array using the filter?

I've been reading the filter documentation for hours but it doesn't seem to have good examples for when the filter only exists within a class/

Comment: Why not hook into `on-hold` instead, and use the hooks to trigger events when `on-hold` is selected? You don't have to create an additional order status in order to hook into existing statuses.

Comment: I'm a little confused by "Which has created the Custom order status, but whenever the order has that status, it is marked as paid." `paid` isn't a status and your custom status shouldn't be triggering any kind of actions except those you have set up.  Does every order go through this process? I'm wondering if maybe you should change the `woocommerce_default_order_status` so that ever order is initially set to "awaiting shipping calculation".